# how to place component in correct order in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Swing and I didn't find enough tutorial to learn it properly. So I start to learn by doing. I tried the following code:-

```
    public class MyGui {
    private JList<String> docList;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listDocModel;

    public MyGui(){

        listDocModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

        try (InputStream resource = MyGui.class.getResourceAsStream("/data.csv");
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                listDocModel.addElement(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("My list below:-");
        mainPanel.add(label);
        docList = new JList<>(listDocModel);
        mainPanel.add(docList);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGui");
        frame.setContentPane(new MyGui().mainPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 400, 400));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

I wanted to have the label on top left corner of the screen and below the list. I don't know how do I do it?

Comment: The tutorial you want is at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/.  The “Laying out components within a container” chapter will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use main panel with a layout manager: `JPanel(LayoutManager layout)`

[LayoutManager oracle.doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

```
mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
//add top
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
JLabel label = new JLabel("My list below:-");
mainPanel.add(label,gbc);
docList = new JList<>(listDocModel);
//add bellow
gbc.gridy = 1;
mainPanel.add(docList,gbc);
```